# Save values of colours in a list for easy access and unclutter environment

Tags: r, list, dataframe, visualization, environment

I have a range of colours that I'm using in R. E.g.

```
odi_dBlue <- "#2254F4"
odi_mBlue <- "#00B7FF"
odi_lBlue <- "#08DEF9"
...
```

This is the simplest way to store them and they can be easily accessed by invoking `"odi_dBlue"` in a graph command.

However, they clutter the environment. What is the best alternative? Dataframe, list etc. and how would you then access them?

Answer (score 1):

you can store other objects in a `list` and obtain them with `get` or `mget`

```
colours <- c(odi_dBlue, odi_mBlue, odi_lBlue)
get(colours[1])
```

About how to access them in the help page it is quite clear how to do it with `get` and `mget`
Although in the `ls` command they will appear too. Or just store directly in a list the values, if you know where it is each colour you can call them directly with `colour[1]`.